# Syntax error in Haskell

Tags: haskell, syntax

I got an error when compiling a Haskell script. Please help:

```
main = do
let bmiTell weight height
    | weight / height ^ 2 <= 18.5 = "You're underweight, you emo, you!"
    | weight / height ^ 2 <= 25.0 = "You're supposedly normal. Pffft, I bet you're ugly!"
    | weight / height ^ 2 <= 30.0 = "You're fat! Lose some weight, fatty!"
    | otherwise                   = "You're a whale, congratulations!"                = "You're a whale, congratulations!"
```

> Error:(3, 5) ghc: parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)

Comment: I believe the `|` in the guard needs to be indents past the `b` in `bmiTell`.

Comment: Scroll to the right. What's that extra bit doing there?

Answer (score 4):

Two problems

- As remarked in comments, your guards need to be indented one extra space at least (so the pipe is more indented that the `b`)
- You need more than just a `let` inside the `do` block. For example, you might want to test out your function!

With those problems fixed:

```
main = do
  let bmiTell weight height
       | weight / height ^ 2 <= 18.5 = "You're underweight, you emo, you!"
       | weight / height ^ 2 <= 25.0 = "You're supposedly normal. Pffft, I bet you're ugly!"
       | weight / height ^ 2 <= 30.0 = "You're fat! Lose some weight, fatty!"
       | otherwise                   = "You're a whale, congratulations!"  
  putStrLn $ bmiTell 6 1
```